# Formly in ng-repeat breaks (due to duplicate IDs?)

Tags: angularjs, angular-formly

I'm editing three records within a single form. The inputs on my elements end up with the same IDs, which breaks things like input validation.

http://plnkr.co/edit/TWXyUzx1Hasw5t36UiQ7?p=preview

Do I need to split these into separate forms? I tried overriding `formlyConfig.extras.getFieldId` to return distinct values, but formly insists on assigning the wrong IDs.

Comment: if I am getting your question right, then i would suggest to use "track by $index" in ng-repeat

Comment: @RohanKawade just tried, no go <div ng-repeat="s in stats track by $index"> still showing validation errors on all fields based on the state of the last one. The ids in question are the DOM element ids, which are supposed to be unique within a page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use formly in a repeat, you need a different array of input for each iteration. Formly puts a bunch of stuff in there, it doesn't just read from it.